# continuous function including hypergeometric function

Tags: pgfplots

How can I plot this pdf in LaTeX?

[image]

I did this

```
\documentclass[a4 , 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    samples at={-20,...,20},

   ]

\addplot [mark=*, cyan] {{(x^2)^0.5}*hypergeompmf(2,1.5,3,1-x^2)}; 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you provide us with the numerical approximation of your hypergeometric function? AFAIK it is an infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

With a numerical approximation obtained from `Wolframalpha`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
%https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2F8)*Hypergeometric2F1%5B2,3%2F2,+3,+1-x%5E2%5D 
%numerical approximation of your function from WolframAlpha
\[\frac{(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{8}~_{2}F_{1}(2,\frac{3}{2};3;1-x^2), ~ x\in R\approx-\frac{x(-x^2+2x-1)}{(2x*(x^2-1)^2)}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={ myfun(\x)  =-x*(-x^2+2*(x)-1)/(2*((x))*(x^2-1)^2)));
                 },
]
\begin{axis}[domain=0.01:10]
% I made a strong assumption that the real-values here includes the 0. But that is only during plotting and not while approximating this function.
\addplot {myfun(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

you can plot

[image]

> **Disclaimer:** This question, IMO, is clearly `out-of-scope` of this forum though. This will belong to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions. And, in this site, we can only help with `TeX` related questions.

Comment: How did u made the approximation?

Comment: @Domas via Wolfram alpha. Check the link attached to this answer in comments. Nevertheless, the explanation is out-of-scope.